# Alguien me puede decir que esta mal en el código

Tags: c

Cuando ejecuto el código, se empiezan a imprimir muchos números y la verdad no entiendo porque ocurre,  yo solo quiero que se imprima una pirámide, en teoría solo debería poner el número de pisos que quiero y debería salir la pirámide.

El código es:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

void piramide(int);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    printf("Ingrese el número de pisos: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    piramide(n);
    system("pause");
}

void piramide(int n){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("%""s",n-i,"");
        for(j=i-1, k=1;k<=2*i-1;k++){
            printf("%d", (k<=1)? ++j%10:--j%10);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Con los cambios que hice, ya solo se ejecuta, me pide el número de pisos y ahí se acaba, no hace nada más.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que tu problema está acá `printf("%""s",n-i,"");`. ¿Qué estabas tratando de hacer ahí? ¿Qué quieres imprimir? ¿Querías hacer `printf("%d",n-i);`?

Comment: Quiero imprimir los números que conformen la pirámide, ya cambie lo que me mandaste, ahora si imprime números y no son infinitos, pero no es como quiero.

Comment: Hola, @Turiex podrías compartir el patrón que quieres imprimir en consola. ¿Qué tipo de pirámide?

Comment: fila 1.- 1
  fila 2.- 232
 fila 3.- 34543
fila 4.- 4567654
fila 5.- 567898765

Comment: @TuriexInYourHeart por favor cambia la etiqueta de `dev-c++` a `c`. La primera se debe usar para el IDE, no para el lenguaje

Comment: Por favor, indica en el título de la pregunta cuál es el problema que estás teniendo. Puede que otros tengan el mismo problema que tú, y no encontrarían tu pregunta si el título dice "Alguien me puede decir qué está mal" :) Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

void piramide(int);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    printf("Ingrese el número de pisos: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    piramide(n);
}



void piramide(int pisos){
    int piso;
    for(piso=1;piso<=pisos;piso++){
        int fila;
        int aux;
        int sucesion=(2*piso)-1;
        printf("%d - ",piso);
        for(fila=0;fila<sucesion;fila++){
             aux=fila+piso;
            if(fila>=piso){
              aux=sucesion-fila+piso-1;
            } 
            printf("%d",aux);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

output:

```c
1 - 1
2 - 232
3 - 34543
4 - 4567654
5 - 567898765
6 - 67891011109876
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: @TuriexInYourHeart
ahi hice unos arreglos que faltaba jeje

Comment: ando re desesperado con otro código, me lo podrías explicar por favor ;-;

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer]. Pulsa en [edit] e indica qué hace este código: recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta) sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Otras personas podrían ver tu código y no entenderían su funcionamiento. _Este sitio no es un repositorio de código_.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es esto:
después de ingresar usa `%i`

dentro de tu método has algo como esto:

```
for( int i = n ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    printf("%i",n-n);
    for( int j = 1 ; j <= n-i ; j++){
        printf("%i",j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

y tu resultado seria si ingresas, por ejemplo el 5

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya andaba desesperado a90d8sadasd.

Comment: por nada, comparte para adquirir mas puntos :)

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace `%i`: lee [answer].